# How to update all the elements of repeated array (fields) of bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

My Table has the schema:

name: String - Nullable

Email: String - Nullable

Contact-number : String - Repeated

age: int64 Nullable

eg:

| Name | Email | Contact-number | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | row | 1256545, 1309045 | 30 |

I want to update both the numbers of the user John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update mytable
set Contact-number = ['0000','1111']
where name = 'John'
```